Step response of MOSFET circuit with capacitors
This question is related to my previously asked question. My question and response is given below.
May I know is my response is correct or not.


A simulator would tell you straight away whether you had got the response right.

There is an inconsistency in the diagram. The MOSFET symbol indicates depletion mode, but Vth=0.5 indicates enhancement mode.

This is an enhancement mosfet

Here is what I get with microcap v12
Seems that there are two "steps" in the Vx waveform.
Exponent function is added in a dotted line ...

Here is another case ...

Update: tried swapping S and D of 2SJ79 ...
V(vm,vp) became also negative ??? Don't know why until now.


May l know why Vx is going below 3V

Actually this is an interview question for Analog Design position. They want only the output waveform. My answer is shown in the question. Don't know it's correct or not

Sorry. Vx is the blue curve ... from 9V, goes to 3 V.

C1 and C2 are discharged by mosfet.
